# removal of white spaces between the letter but other words shouldn't get affected

Tags: python, nlp, preprocessor

```py
    get_elements(files[2]) = {'Nationality': 'Indian',
    'Date of Birth': '26-06-1989',
    'Gender': 'Male',
    'Marital Status': 'Married',
    'Languages Known': ['English' ,'Hindi','Telugu'],
    'Passport No': 'U8685434',
    'Valid Till': '22/02/2021',
    'TECHNICAL QUALIFICATION':{
        '➢ Operating Systems':['Windows 10/8/7/XP', 'MAC'],
        '➢ Programming Languages':['PHP', 'Java', '.Net'],
        '➢ Web Technologies':['HTML','CSS','JavaScript', 'Angular',
    'JS (Jquery , Bootstrap)'],
    '➢ Frameworks':['Wo r d p r e s s ',' C o d e i g n i t e r' ]}}
```

I tried below code where I want to compress "Wo r d p r e s s , C o d e i g n i t e r" as wordpress,codeigniter and rest of the word/string should remain at the same position as it is.

I tried below:-

```py
    text = str(get_elements(files[2])).lower().replace("\\n","").replace("➢","•").replace(' ','')
```

but the output is not promising since entire text is being compromised in the get_elements(files[2]).

Comment: @Jech Chua you tried well but i think it is still not in the format. A variable name in python can't  have '()' or '[]'.How do we do it now..? The user who asked the question seems to be non-reponsive.

Comment: @AjaySinghRana it was more of `==` than literal `=`. Just assign to any variable name and you're good to go, the source of the text is not the problem at all

Answer (score 1):

You can use slicing to get some replacements to work only on Frameworks part:

```py
text = """ 'Nationality               : Indian',
 'Date of Birth      : 26-06-1989',
 'Gender                     : Male',
 'Marital Status          : Married',
 'Languages Known   : English ,',
 'Hindi,',
 'Telugu',
 'Passport No            : U8685434',
 'Valid Till                 : 22/02/2021',
 'TECHNICAL QUALIFICATION',
 '➢ Operating Systems            :',
 'Windows 10/8/7/XP, MAC.',
 '➢ Programming Languages  :',
 'PHP, Java, .Net',
 '➢ Web Technologies            :',
 'HTML,CSS,JavaScript, Angular',
 'JS    (Jquery , Bootstrap)',
 '➢ Frameworks                      :',
 'Wo r d p r e s s , C o d e i g n i t e r ,'"""

# global substitutions
text = text.lower().replace("\n", "").replace("➢","•")
# slice and modify only the second slice, after frameworks
text = text[:text.find("frameworks")]+text[text.find("frameworks"):].replace(' ','')
```

You will have to add stuff for the weird lots of spaces, but the frameworks got merged like you wanted:

```
>>> print(text)
 'nationality               : indian', 'date of birth      : 26-06-1989', 'gender                     : male', 'marital status          : married', 'languages known   : english ,', 'hindi,', 'telugu', 'passport no            : u8685434', 'valid till                 : 22/02/2021', 'technical qualification', '• operating systems            :', 'windows 10/8/7/xp, mac.', '• programming languages  :', 'php, java, .net', '• web technologies            :', 'html,css,javascript, angular', 'js    (jquery , bootstrap)', '• frameworks:','wordpress,codeigniter,'
```

Comment: That's great !! but the question is how we can generalize the same for 1000 documents like this we encounter. Do we need to create specific lookups or we even not sure these spaces you may receive in headers of documents. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated

Comment: If it's always one letter with spaces around (and you don't mind some false-positives when real one-letter stuff loses its spaces), then it's easy, use regex. If there's no pattern like that, then it would be impossible without analysing the text itself. | Regex substitution in a loop: `re.sub(r" (\w) ", r"\1", text)` - \w is unicode word character, I put spaces around it. \1 would put the captured group (that one character) back, no spaces around this time